# Passing hidden values, html

Tags: php, html

I have a the following php file. displayitems.php

```
<?php
     *
     *
     *
   echo "<form action='http://retailthree.nn4m.co.uk/alex/add_data.html'>";
   echo   "<input type='hidden' name='value' value='$value'/>";
   echo   "<button type='submit'>Add</button>";
   echo "</form>";
 ?>
```

Then the html file. add_data.html:

```
  <form method="post" name="form">            
        <table id="mytable" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>Trend <input type="text" name="trend" size="20"></td>
                  //many other fields
            </tr>
        </table>
  </forn>
```

Then the aforementioned html will perform an action on a php file.
However that I want to achieve is to pass the hidden data ->$value from the first php file, to the Trend input box(to print the $value content to the input box). Is this possible?

Comment: So you would like the previously entered value to go in the input box on form submit?

Comment: Yes, exactly. How can I do this?

Comment: it is not possible until your  add_data.html is html if you convert it to php it can be possible

Answer (score 2):

You would simple use the posted variable and place it in the value attribute of your `<input>` like so:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_GET['value'] ?>" name="trend" size="20">
```

Of course you should do some validation before echoing it to the `<input>`

EDIT:

Quite rightly mentioned by @ocanal - `GET` is the default method for forms. You will not be able to process these forms with PHP if your file is *.html it must be a *.php file.

Comment: nice but there is no method tag for form, so default method is `GET`. And as  @Pankaj Khairnar mentioned the file type must be php. you may add it to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

change the name of `add_data.html` file to `add_data.php` use following code in `add_data.php` file

```
<?php
// your php code
?>

<form method="post" name="form">            
  <table id="mytable" border="1">
    <tr>
     <td>
        Trend <input type="text" name="trend" size="20"  
                       value="<?php echo $_POST['trend'] ?>">
     </td>
      //many other fields
    </tr>
 </table>
 </forn>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little lost but assuming you mean that you want the hidden value to appear in a text input field on another page I would suggest this:

HTML page

```
<form name='form' action='yourPhpFile.php' method='POST'>
    <input name='hiddenGuy' type='hidden' value='hello from the hidden guy'/>
    <input type='submit' value='Send'/>
</from>
```

Now for your php file called yourPhpFile.php

```
<?php
    //your value from the hidden field will be held in the array $_POST from the previous document.
    //the key depends on your field's name.
    $val = $_POST['hiddenGuy'];
    echo "<form name='form' action='yourPhpFile.php' method='POST'>
    <input name='showingInText' type='text' value='".$val."'/>
</from>";
?>
```

This can be achieved on the same page too by removing the form action attribute. and echoing the a different input type and value depending on whether $_POST is set using the isset method.

```
if(isset($_POST['hiddenGuy'])){
    echo "<input name='showingInText' type='text' value='".$_POST['hiddenGuy']."'/>";
}
else{
    echo "<input name='hiddenGuy' type='hidden' value='hello from the hidden guy'/>
    <input type='submit' value='Send'/>";
}
```